# Flask url_for('index', _external=True) creates url with double ip?

Tags: python, url, nginx, flask, gunicorn

I've got a [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org) website which was running fine on a test-machine which I just call with an ip-address. I now deployed some new code, and  `url_for('index', _external=True)` suddenly gives out an address in which it lists the (correct) ip address twice with a comma in between:

```
http://52.29.15.xxx,52.29.15.xxx/
```

I have no `SERVER_NAME` defined in my `config.py` (which used to work fine until today) and I'm running on [gunicorn](http://gunicorn.org) behind an [nginx](http://nginx.org/) server.

I tried adding `SERVER_NAME = '52.29.15.xx'` to my config.py, but then I get a 404 on every url I try (and so the website doesn't work at all anymore).

I guess the problem lies in nginx which passes along a weird location or something?

Does anybody know how I can solve this? All tips are welcome!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, after some fiddling around I found I had an error in my nginx config. I actually had the following two lines in two places in my config (which is why I didn't notice it):

```
proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
proxy_set_header Host $host;
```

which caused the ip address to appear twice in the Flask request context.

I now removed the first line, and everything works beautifully again.. :-)

Answer (score 0):

In general, there is no need to explicitly do `proxy_set_header Host $proxy_host` or `proxy_set_header Host $http_host`. If you need to call a server by something other than what is in the `proxy_pass` directive, then you will need to override via `proxy_set_header` something. In my case, when generating sitemap.xml, I was getting the IP address mentioned twice which was finally resolved by removing both of the lines (not either/or). Hope this helps someone.